# SEO H1 and IMG tag issue

Tags: html, seo

I'm trying to add some keyword in H1 and IMG alt, but I found the H1 tag has been used for display product name.

I don't have permission to edit product name so I can't append keyword after product name.

For example, here's what I see the exist solution :

```
<h1 itemprop="name" class="some_css_class" id="PRODUCT_TITLE">Summer Room Diffuser</h1>
<h1 hidden="hidden">SEO keyword been put here...</h1>
```

It puts SEO keyword in another hidden H1 tag...

Will it low down SEO rank ?
It so, what should I do to fix it ?

---

Another problem is IMG alt, the page used some jQuery plug-in for product image display.

So, the product image isn't in an IMG tag but a DIV, like this :

```
<div class="tile" data-scale="1.5" data-image="https://someweb.com/img/product/12345.jpg"></div> <!-- this tag shows a visible image on page -->
```

Also, it put an IMG tag but make it hidden.

```
<div style="display: none"><img alt="Image ALT text goes here..." src="https://someweb.com/img/product/12345.jpg" /></div>
```

I'm not sure if it will suffer SEO rank, how can I improve it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score -1):

Don't put more than one H1 element on a page to be safe regarding SEO. It could harm your rankings because the crawlers won't be able to contextualize the page.

For the image, in the past Google has discouraged making images hidden but I don't think they penalize your for doing it. I think this is because they encourage lazy-loading images and a perceivably faster site too. Use good descriptive ALT text and filenames as much as possible.